How to find files path in QT android and show the files (Image) from Internal Storage Android
So i want make a program that can show image from internal Android files (so i dont need to update the apk to show/ + new image, user can just give and pick himself) with you as user will just type your name and show it, to make it happen i need to know with path it is, for that i make a "show image with you pick it" APK.
it goes like this in qt widget
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Dialog to choose an image
    QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open Image", "/storage/emulated/0", "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)");
    if (!filePath.isEmpty()) {
        // Set the file path to the label for displaying path
        ui->labelFilePath->setWordWrap(true);
        ui->labelFilePath->setText(filePath);

        QPixmap pixmap(filePath);
        if (!pixmap.isNull()) {
            ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(ui->label->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
        }
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



it is do well but the output is something like content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fdio.jpg, instead something like /sdcard/Download/dio.jpg fyi this was the real path that i can use too, that i found it in android studio
after that i make the show one who like this
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include \<QFileDialog\>
#include \<QPixmap\>
#include \<QMessageBox\>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget \*parent)
: QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui-\>setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::\~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QString filename = ui-\>filename-\>text();

    // Tambahkan pengecekan panjang teks jika diperlukan
    if (filename.length() < 1) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Input Error", "Please enter at least 1 characters for the filename.");
        return;
    }
    
    //QString imagePath = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2F"+filename+".jpg";
    QString imagePath = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fjoko.jpg";
    //QString imagePath = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A" + filename + ""; //19,20,21
    //QString imagePath = "document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/"+filename+".jpg";
    QImage image(imagePath);
    
    if (!image.isNull()) {
        QImage scaledImage = image.scaled(ui->label->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    
        // Ubah QImage ke QPixmap
        QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(scaledImage);
    
        // Pastikan pixmap tidak null
        if (!pixmap.isNull()) {
            ui->label->setFixedSize(pixmap.size());
            ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);
            ui->label->update();
        } else {
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Load Error", "Failed to convert image.");
        }
    } else {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Load Error", "The image could not be loaded. Please check the filename and file path.");

}
}

the problem was

it never show your typing if not 12 char++
i already typed but nothing show
12++ char its showing

when you press button, it just show only half, you need click the line edit to make it full
half show
full when you clock lineedit


**the setup was, android 9, SDK 28, JDK 19.0.2.7, with kit Android 6.7 x86
**
this is the setup
FYI i make first program with qtQuick Cmake, and its complete mess (force close), and i make the second program with QtQuick Qmake and it do fine is path is ok like (sdcard/Download/"+filename+".jpg) but not work with (Content://...)
Solving to show the real path of files, not just content:// or bypass all of that

Please don't use comments to update your question, instead [edit] it.

Already fixed it
